# How To Match Data using Excel

Tags: excel

I have my data in a spreadsheet through 3 columns.

```
 RC Number      UserName    Id
SOW-2017-002    11231683    RESOURCE A
SOW-2016-005    11121752    RESOURCE B
SOW-2017-002    11231827    RESOURCE C
SOW-2017-001    10667179    RESOURCE D
SOW-2016-003    11192520    RESOURCE E
SOW-2016-003    11071347    RESOURCE F
```

I want to find all username and ID tagged to RC Numbers

Example:

```
  SOW-2017-002   

  11231683 RESOURCE A

  11231827 RESOURCE C
```

I tried using the formula;

```
=INDEX(Roster!B2:B7,MATCH(A3,A2:A7,0))
```

it's giving me the first correct value however the second one it just copy the value above.

Comment: Welcome to [so], please take a [tour] and check [ask] and better to provide [mcve].  Without sample, we not sure what data you want to match, what result you are expected.

Comment: thank you for responding. i have added a snippet of data.

Comment: You are welcome, but I can't understand the requirement, what data will be filtered and by what criteria.  And you can provide demo or fake data (but fit your criteria), and please provide in text format, which allow us to simulate it.

Comment: edited it again. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming your data is layed out as per the image above, place the value you want to search for in G3, and the following formula in I3.  Copy it to the right and down as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$D$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$3:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)/($G$3=$B$3:$B$8)),ROW(A1)),MATCH(I$2,$C$2:$D$2,0)),"")
```

Comment: thank you for your response. sorry for the late reply. got sidetracked to another issue. anyways will this formula work if the results should be showed in another sheet?

Comment: yes, but references to things in the B2:D8 area will need to be prefixed by the sheetname.  Excel will add this automatically when you select cells on a different sheet within the workbook when you are creating/editing a formula.  if I was referencing cell A2:B3 on sheet4, the reference in excel would look like `Sheet4!A2:B3`.  if the sheet name has a space in it you will need ' at both ends of the sheet name.  ie. `'Sheet Name 4'!A2:B3`

Comment: i was able to configure it however its now giving me an error of too many arguements on the match end with "".

Comment: Probably one too many commas or a misplaced )...type in the formula you are trying to use and I will see if I can edit it for you.